# How to detect google maps Geojson feature click?

Tags: swift, google-maps, swiftui, geojson

I'm developing an app include google map ?
And I draw countries with geojson and I want to give click action when I click on country.

I'm developing it with swiftui framework.

**My Code like this :**

```
func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
        
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "countries", ofType: "json")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let geoJsonParser = GMUGeoJSONParser(url: url)
        geoJsonParser.parse()
                
       
        
            for county in countries {
            
                switch county.countryId {
                
                case 2 : drawTurkey(geoJson : geoJsonParser,model : county,mapView : mapView)
                case 3 : drawUSA(geoJson : geoJsonParser,model : county,mapView : mapView)
                case 4 : drawChina(geoJson : geoJsonParser,model : county,mapView : mapView)
                default: drawBrasil(geoJson : geoJsonParser,model : county,mapView : mapView)
                    
                }
             }
            
            
            
    
        let renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(map: mapView, geometries: geoJsonParser.features)
            renderer.render()
        
        
        
    }


And Draw Turkey Metots like this : 

func drawTurkey(geoJson : GMUGeoJSONParser,model : CountryGeneralInformationModel,mapView: GMSMapView){
        let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.335742 , longitude: 27.123613 )
        marker.title = "İzmir"
        marker.snippet = "Welcome to İzmir"
        marker.map = mapView
        
        for feature in geoJson.features {
            if let feature = feature as? GMUFeature {
               let properties = feature.properties
                if(properties?.first?.value as! String == "TUR"){
                    feature.style = GMUStyle(styleID: "feat_1", stroke: nil, fill: UIColor(generateColor(effiency : model.effValue)), width: 2, scale: 1, heading: 1, anchor: CGPoint.zero, iconUrl: nil, title: "afdss" , hasFill: true, hasStroke: true)}}

        }
        
    }
```

**My Question is how to detect when I click feature ?**

Answer (score 1):

Use GMSMapView delegate function didTap(at overlay). Note: currently I have found no way to attach data to the geo json overlays that are rendered.

Comment: came across this because this is what i am looking for. they said to set the isTappable property of the overlay to true. After that, then what? The function they keep saying gets triggered func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) doesnt get triggered. Do we override this? or how to apply it in swiftui when map is under a UIRepresentable?